# How to make a folder accessible to users of a certain group on linux

Tags: linux, permissions, unix, chown

I tried to make a the /opt/apps folder accessible to all users of the 'www' group. The main user of the group would be the 'jboss' user, so I runned:

```
sudo chown -R jboss:www /opt/apps
```

Both the 'jboss' and the 'ubuntu' user are in the 'www' group, but only the 'jboss' user can write in the /opt/apps folder.

How can I make the /opt/apps folder writable to all users in the 'www' group?

Comment: What permissions are set on /opt/apps folder? 644? 777? etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the permissions of that folder as well as the group and owner.

```
ls -l
```

will show them.

If the group does not have write permissions then just

```
chmod g+w /opt/apps
```

and you might need to do that recursively with the -r flag to chmod

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want the "www" group to have 'read', 'write' and 'execute' privileges on the "/opt/apps" folder (directory) and subdirectories.

In that case, use the [`chmod`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?chmod) command like this:

`sudo chmod -R g+rwx /opt/apps`